# how to calculate specific cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel sheet which cells contain both string and numeric values. I have a problem calculating numeric values. I need a function that will check cells in given range and calculate(sum) numeric values. Result have to be : 8+4+10+12+12+5=51
[image: given range]

To get 8 and 4 values from 8/4b and 8b/4 I use this function:

```
=IF(LEN(L27)=4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(L27,2))),RIGHT(L27,1),LEFT(L27,1)),L27)
```

This function works well, but
1) it returns 8 and 4 values as char, not as number. So SUM function gives error.
2) how can I do the function to check cells in range and SUM them under those conditions (conditions in my function above)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

`=IF(LEN(L27)=4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(L27,2))),VALUE(RIGHT(L27,1)),VALUE(LEFT(L27,1))),L27)`

**Edit:**

To put this all into one formula, I could only come up with this monster:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(I27:N27)=4),--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(I27:N27,2)))),IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(I27:N27,1))),VALUE(RIGHT(I27:N27,1)),0))+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(I27:N27)=4),--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",RIGHT(I27:N27,2)))),IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(I27:N27,1))),VALUE(LEFT(I27:N27,1)),0))+SUM(I27:N27)}
```

This is an array formula, so you need to enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. These brackets `{}` will then appear automatically. Do not enter them by hand.

As for the range, change `I27:N27` to your range.

Comment: Thank you Sun. it works well converts to numbers. How about if I add SUM function and range ?? for example: =_SUM_(IFERROR(--IF(LEN(_C27:J27_)=4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(_C27:J27_,2))),‌​R.....

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the data shown in your question is from `H27` to `Q27`.
Use below formula to accomplish what you are looking for:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(IF(LEN(H27:Q27)=4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(H27:Q27,2))),RIGHT(H27:Q27,1),LEFT(H27:Q27,1)),H27:Q27)),0))
```

This is an array formula so commit the formula by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Just to let you know, to convert a char to number you can use `VALUE` function as:

```
=VALUE(IF(LEN(L27)=4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(L27,2))),RIGHT(L27,1),LEFT(L27,1)),L27))
```

Comment: Hi Mrig
thank you for your function. And thanks all friends who helped me.
Please, can you help me with VBA code of this function?? I need to create function in VBA

Comment: @MamedAliyev - If you want this to do via a function what parameters will you be passing to the function?

Comment: I want our new VBA function perform like excel function which you helped

Comment: @MamedAliyev - Is your range constant or you want this formula to be applicable to different ranges. If your range is not constant, what input you will be passing to the function, like you'll provide range to the function or something else.

Comment: range will be different

Comment: @MamedAliyev - gave an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434118/create-vba-function-based-on-user-defined-function/37436950#37436950).

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
=IFERROR(--IF(LEN(L27)=4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(L27,2))),RIGHT(L27,1),LEFT(L27,1)),L27),0)
```

Comment: Thank you bro. it works well. How can I add SUM function and range ??
for example: =**SUM**(IFERROR(--IF(LEN(**C27:J27**)=4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(**C27:J27**,2))),R

Comment: =SUM(C4:J4,IFERROR(--IF(LEN(L27)=4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(L27,2))),RIGHT(L27,1),LEFT(L27,1)),L27),0))

Comment: Replace C4:J4 to your desired range :)

Comment: @Sixthsense Regarding your sum function, I think this does not find all the cells with len() = 4.

Comment: @MamedAliyev does it have to be in one formula? would your worksheet structure allow for a help row?

Comment: yeah I want to be one formula. both functions you helped me return 39(10+12+12+5). not affect 8/4b or 8b/4 . =SUM(C27:J27,IFERROR(--IF(LEN(C27:J27)=4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",LEFT(C27:J27,2))),RIGHT(C27:J27,1),LEFT(C27:J27,1)),C27:J27),0))